# Get the start and end of the week date with R

Tags: r, shiny

I want to find the beginning and end of the week of the entered date. That is, Sunday and Saturday dates.

#### app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    dateInput("date", "date"),
    textOutput("date_sun"),
    textOutput("date_satur")
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    observe({
      
      date_sel <- input$date
      week <- wday(date_sel)
      
      if(week == 1){
        sun <- date_sel
        satur <- date_sel + 6
      }else if(week == 2){
        sun <- date_sel - 1
        satur <- date_sel + 5
      }else if(week == 3){
        sun <- date_sel - 2
        satur <- date_sel + 4
      }else if(week == 4){
        sun <- date_sel - 3
        satur <- date_sel + 3
      }else if(week == 5){
        sun <- date_sel - 4
        satur <- date_sel + 2
      }else if(week == 6){
        sun <- date_sel - 5
        satur <- date_sel + 1
      }else if(week == 7){
        sun <- date_sel - 6
        satur <- date_sel
      }
      
      output$date_sun <- renderPrint(sun)
      output$date_satur <- renderPrint(satur)
      
    })
  })
```

Realized with the above code. But it's not beautiful.
Couldn't it be more concise code?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `lubridate` you can use `floor_date` and `ceiling_date` with `units` as `'weeks'` to get start and end date of the week.

```
library(lubridate)
x <- as.Date("2020-01-01") 
floor_date(x, 'weeks')
#[1] "2019-12-29"

ceiling_date(x, 'weeks') - 1
#[1] "2020-01-04"
```

Answer (score 4):

We can actually handle this quite easily in base R using `strftime` to obtain the weekday number (0 to 6):

```
x <- as.Date("2020-01-01")    # January 1 was a Wednesday
x - as.numeric(strftime(x, "%w"))
x + 7 - as.numeric(strftime(x, "%w")) - 1

[1] "2019-12-29"
[1] "2020-01-04"
```

Note that the 29th of December 2019 was a Sunday, while the 4th of January 2020 was a Saturday.